# Unsure of how to wrangle my javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, npm

I am using NPM and some angular packages. I am trying to follow this tutorial, part 1: Basic Grid [link](http://blog.backand.com/ng-grid-and-a-simple-rest-api/)

My file directory setup is:

D:/nodeStuff/uiGrid, which contains:

```
node_modules  uigrid.css  uigrid.html  uigrid.js
```

The node_modules folder contains:

```
angular  angular-animate  angular-touch  angular-ui-grid
```

I can't solve this error in my browser console:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-touch due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-touch' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I know the tutorial provides a jsfiddle, but it imported dependencies in the css (is that normal?) and I am stumped on how to make it work outside of jsfiddle

My html:

```
<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
<script src="./node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="./uigrid.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-touch', 'ui.grid']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    }, {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    }, {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }];
}]);
```

My CSS:

```
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name for angular-touch is `ngTouch` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch). Try changing your javascript to

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
```